# SQL Unique Where and Count

Tags: sql, oracle

I may be asking this question wrong, and that's part of my problem, but:

Columns on Project_Table:

```
ProjectID, ProjectName, StartDate, EndDate, Coordinator
```

Columns on Donation_Table:

```
DonationID, DonationAMT, DonationDate, ProjectID
```

So, I am trying to do a count to see how many pledges have been made for each project.

Desired output would be:

```
ProjectId, ProjectName, #ofPledges
```

I can get a specific count with:

```
SELECT count(ProjectID) FROM Donation_Table where ProjectID = 1;
```

But I am fighting to get the ProjectName to show, which comes from my Project_Table; while displaying all results, not just a SPECIFIC ProjectID. I want to see all of my ProjectID's, all of the ProjectName's, and then the count of how many donations each of those projects have received. Is it possible to display all of this at once?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A join and a group by is what you need:

```
SELECT P.ProjectID, P.ProjectName, Count(DonationID)
FROM Project_Table P
JOIN Donation_Table D ON P.ProjectID = D.ProjectID
GROUP BY P.ProjectID, P.ProjectName
```

This is simple stuff and probably to basic a skill to require a question on stackoverflow.  I suggest reading about how to use SQL -- any decent book or article will cover this in the first few chapters.

NB if you want to see zero donation items you will need a left join:

```
SELECT P.ProjectID, P.ProjectName, Count(DonationID)
FROM Project_Table P
LEFT JOIN Donation_Table D ON P.ProjectID = D.ProjectID
GROUP BY P.ProjectID, P.ProjectName
```

Comment: I think you should have a `left join` to get all the projects.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - True this will not have projects with 0 donations

Comment: Yes, the problem I ran into was not using the GROUP BY with my LEFT JOIN. I was getting very frustrated and this helped immensely. Thank you! I have been reading up on SQL, and some of those manuals leave me awfully confused, which is why I finally resulted to asking on here.

Answer (score 0):

First determine the number of donations per project:

```
SELECT ProjectID, count(*) 
FROM Donation_Table 
GROUP BY ProjectID
```

The result is a new table that you can join with your projects table:

```
SELECT p.*, x.cnt
FROM Project_Table p
JOIN (
    SELECT ProjectID, count(*) as cnt 
    FROM Donation_Table 
    GROUP BY ProjectID
) X
    ON X.ProjectID = p.ProjectID
```